# GSAP Tween not easing with ScrollMagic in React

Tags: reactjs, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm trying to ease a progress bar filling animation but when it gets triggered it jumps straight to 100%. I'm using `react-scrollmagic` and `react-gsap`. Progress bar is from Bulma framework.

This is my code:

```
<Controller>
<Scene
    pin={false}
    reverse={false}
    indicators={true}
    triggerElement= "#trigger1"
    duration={0}
>
        <Tween staggerFrom={{ value: 0, ease: 'Expo.easeOut' }} staggerTo={{ value: 100, ease: 'Expo.easeOut' }} stagger={0.15}>
            <div id="trigger1"></div>
            <progress className="progress is-primary" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </Tween>
        </Scene>
</Controller>
```

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: I'm not seeing a duration for your tween anywhere. Did you set one?

Comment: @ZachSaucier My objective is to trigger the animation on scroll, so i have to set duration=0, like the first example here https://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_tweening.html

Comment: The "Smurf me" example on that page still has a positive duration on the Scene. Maybe demo 3 of [GSAP's article about working with ScrollMagic](https://greensock.com/scrollmagic) can help. Otherwise I recommend the [GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/) as you're likely to get better help more quickly there.

Comment: This has been [answered on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/21264-tween-not-easing-with-scrollmagic-in-react/).